# Do I have to duplicate views in an ExtJS Universal app for modern and classic toolkit?

Tags: extjs

I am not new with ExtJS, building apps since ExtJS3, but I am definitely new with ExtJS universal apps.
What I undertand is that, in an universal app, we have to define both classic and modern views separately, in classic and modern subfolders. Doing so, both views can share the same Models, Stores, ...

Does it mean that classic and modern views are completely separated? Is there a way to use a classic view in "modern" mode, I mean when loading application on a phone?
Or should I have to completely duplicate my views, if I want to have the exact same functionnality using the application on a desktop and on a phone?

I already read the Sencha docs, but that part is not really clear for me...

Thanks in advance !

LuD_GRi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When starting a new project, which toolkit should I use?
>   Question details: We’re currently starting development of a completely new app – initially for desktop, but later we’ll add support for phones. What’s the recommended way of building this type of app that is the most future proof? Should we go for a universal app and create our initial desktop app with the Classic toolkit, or is a Modern toolkit only app the best approach from now on?
>
> We recommend the Modern toolkit for most new projects, but there are several features in the Classic toolkit that would also make it the right choice. The following features are only available in Classic: locking grids, support for IE8 / 9 / 10, and accessibility and support for RTL (Right-to-left) languages. If your application needs these capabilities, then Classic is the way to go.
>   [link](https://www.sencha.com/blog/whats-new-in-ext-js-6-5-and-sencha-cmd-6-5-your-questions-answered/)

I think you can mix both of these approaches in one case - if supporting older browser versions such as IE8\7\6 is not important to you. Honestly, I have not tried to mix them. and not sure if this will work. I think this is unjustified
Modern toolkit is created not only for mobile devices. This is generally a toolkit aimed at fresh versions of browsers, and free from unnecessary tricks to support things specific to each version.

*EDIT*:
[link2](https://www.sencha.com/blog/using-both-shared-and-view-specific-code-in-an-ext-js-6-universal-app/)

> By design, the classic and modern toolkits target different generations of browsers. If you write an application with both classic and modern user interfaces, the user sees one or the other, depending on the runtime environment. **You cannot mix and match view components.** But both toolkits do share core features, such as the class system, the data package, the view-controller-viewmodel architecture, etc.

Comment: Thank you @pvlt ! So, I will go for the modern toolkit, as maintaining two differents UI will be a lot of extra work ...